# JSF - UISelectItems problem

Tags: java, jsf, uicomponents

Strange error i received from compiler:

```
Expected a child component type of UISelectItem/UISelectItems for component type javax.faces.SelectOne(siachoice).  Found javax.faces.component.UISelectItems.
```

So, if he was expecting UISelectItems, and found UISelectItems, then where is the error?

My JSP implementation:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="siachoice" value="#{dbSelectBean.currentOption}">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{dbSelectBean.dbs}" />
                            </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Method, where i am setting UISelectItem to UISelectItems:

```
private UISelectItems populateDatabases(String databaseString) {
    UISelectItems selects = new UISelectItems();
    List<UISelectItem> result = new ArrayList<UISelectItem>();
    StringTokenizer tokeniz = new StringTokenizer(databaseString, GlobalConstants.DELIMITER);
    while(tokeniz.hasMoreTokens()){
        String tempDB = tokeniz.nextToken();
        UISelectItem item = new UISelectItem();
        item.setItemValue(tempDB);
        item.setItemLabel(tempDB);
        result.add(item);
    }
    selects.setValue(result);

    return selects;
}
```

Then, of course, i am setting it to the bean variable dbs.

Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must return a `Collection` of `javax.faces.model.SelectItem`

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add(new SelectItem(value, label));
```

return list;

Answer (score 4):

The `<f:selectItems value="#{bean.items}" />` expects one of the following values:

```
public SelectItem[] getItems() {}

public List<SelectItem> getItems() {}

public Map<String, Object> getItems() {}
```

The commonly used one is indeed the `List<SelectItem>`.

**Edit**: as response to the comment: `UISelectItem` represents the `<f:selectItem>` component. The same applies to `UISelectItems` and `<f:selectItems>`. E.g.

```
<f:selectItem binding="#{bean.selectItem}" />
<f:selectItems binding="#{bean.selectItems}" />
```

which are bound as

```
private UISelectItem selectItem;
private UISelectItems selectItems;
// +getter +setter
```

this way you can control the components programmatically -as for every other `UIComponent`.

Comment: Then what`s the difference between SelectItem and UISelectItem?

Comment: SelectItem represents the value. UISelectItem represents the Component.

Answer (score 1):

```
<h:form>
<h:selectOneListbox size="5"  >

<f:selectItems  value="#{userManager.Test()}" />
</h:selectOneListbox>
</h:form>
```

---

```
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;
import tn.com.ttnproject.entity.*;

@Name("userManager")
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
public class UserManager {
    public  List <SelectItem> listAllUsersNames;
    SelectItem element;
    public List<SelectItem> Test(){ 
        listAllUsersNames = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        for (int i=1;i<=10;i++)
        {
            element=new SelectItem(
                new Integer(i),
                i+".00 euros",
                "Produit à "+i+".00 euros");
            listAllUsersNames.add(element);
        }
        return listAllUsersNames;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is UISelectItem is a component clas so it has to be paired with jsf tag by `binding` attribute. If you want to have *pure* values you have to use [SelectItem(s)](http://developers.sun.com/docs/jscreator/apis/jsf/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html) classes.